# using other java files in my java project

Tags: java, eclipse

first of all, I have to say that this is my first attempt to do something with eclipse and java. Now, I've just open a new java project in eclipse called `alignmentComparision`. In addition to this, I have a java code, which I need to use in my newly created `alignmentComparision` project. To explain my problem clearly, I can give a similar c++ example. Assume that I have a file `superposition.cpp` and `superposition.h` and I created a cpp file whose name is `alignmentComparision.cpp`. By getting superposition.h, superposition.cpp and alignmentComparision.cpp at the same folder and adding `#include superposition.h` line to my alignmentComparision.cpp , I can call the functions inside superposition file. How could I do similar thing in the eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you create your source files in packages.
A package is actually a directory path that is mentioned on top of your source code.
For instance your source Superposition.java file could be in package com.mycompany.myapp
As consequences this source file is in directory `com/mycompany/myapp` starting from your root source directory.
The first line of code of this source must be `package com.mycompany.myapp;`.
In this source file if you need to use another class that is defined in another source file in the same package you do not have to do anything special.  Just use it.
But if you need to use another class from a source file that is in another package than you must import that class just below the package statement and before the class definition.
Example:

```
package com.mycompay.myapp.service;

import com.mycompany.myapp.model.MyModelClass;

class MyClass {
  MyModelClass model = new MyModelClass();
  // code here
}
```

You may also import all the classes from a package.  for instance if you want to use several classes from package `com.mycompany.myapp.model` you may add an import statement for each or use a wildcard: `import com.mycompany.myapp.*;`  With this you can use all classes from that package in your class `MyClass`.  Usually IDE automatically add import statements and you do not have to bother with them if the classes you need are in the classpath.  It is the case if you are using classes from the same project.
To automatically add import statement with Eclipse press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and with netbeans <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use `import path.to.my.Class;`. If you struggle with basic things such as this, I would suggest getting to know Javas syntax by doing [a Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you see following structure in eclipse package explorer like below:

```
alignmentComparision
     src
        default package
             A.java
             B.java
```

if you want to call method say static in A from B, you could do something like:

```
A.abc();
```

If you want to create new instance of A and call method from it, you could do the following:

```
A a  = new A();//similar to C++ new operator to create instance
a.method();
```

Similar to include in C++, you have import in java. So if you have your java source in multiple directories (we call it package in java), you could import those. Instead of specifying exact name as in C++, you could use wildcard in Java something like:

```
import com.mycompany.mypackage.*;
```

For More details checkout [oracle's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) doc.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with eclipse and everything to do with Java. You need to make sure the different files are in the same package or are imported, similar to what you need to do in C++ (but using different keywords).

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse right click on the folder that your project is in and select "Build Path" then select "Add External Archive..."

Then you need to do the import the class into your program.

Without doing the

```
import <pathtojar>/<jarfile>
```

this will allow you to do this

```
import <jarfile>
```